# Wireless Relay triggered by continuous voltage

Tags: relay, wireless

Does anyone know of a wireless relay product that can be triggered by continuous voltage?  Obviously that is how a wired relay works, I just want to add a load to a spot that has 12v already wired but i don't want to have to run a  trigger wire to that spot.

Ideally I would like to simply connect a premade transmitter to a existing switch.  For my current application I have a light on one side of my boat, I want to make another light on the other side go on as well but without running a cable to it.  I just want to put a relay inline and leave its switch on such that the switch on the other side light controls both lights.

I have found almost what i want in the form a of a relay and a small key fob remote, but that is not what i need.  Alternatively I might be better asking how to make a transmitter for the above product that is triggered by applying a constant voltage??? The above light project is my current application, but if I could make/buy something it could be applied all over my boat and be really useful in avoiding the pain and destruction involved in running wires on my boat.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a zigbee, esp32 or other wireless micro?

Answer (score 1):

Wireless remote switches use RF encoded to target switches with latch memory. Common consumer products eg garage openers and may be found by searching... RF remote switch

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  To clarify:   "I have found almost what i want in the form a of a relay and a small key fob remote, but that is not what i need."

Comment: WHy not ? it has a switch and you have a light and 12V

Comment: My goal is to add load control to a switch panel that is already installed-- adding a trigger wire from the panel to the area i want to control would involve a long and circuitous rout that would inevitably damage walls ect. that i have gone to great trouble to make look nice.   I am not looking for "a" solution i am looking for a "good" solution.

Comment: This is a great solution if done behind control panel with remote On and RF to control it.  They should tiny be tinyPCB but antenna can use gnd wire.

Comment: Ok, maybe my question should have been:  How do I make/mod the remote to trigger from a DC signal--- 12v remote signals relay on, 0v remote signals relay off?

Comment: it’s just 2 series switches. RF is latching  toggle , manual is always On

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ready-made products, but they're not exactly cutting edge technology.

Easiest but funkiest solution:

> [X10 Powerflash Burglar Alarm Interface](https://www.x10.com/psc01-powerflash-burgular-alarm-interface.html). It has 2 screw terminals which will accept your 12 V (AC or DC) trigger signal. It transmits a wireless X10 signal (carried by the power line, not radio waves) to an X10 device. The X10 device can be a plug-in or hard-wired 110V relay. This is 1970's technology and occasionally other devices in your home can interfere with the X10 power line signals.

Newer solution that requires more work:

> [Insteon Remote Control Plug-In Low Voltage Controller.](https://www.smarthome.com/products/i-o-linc-insteon-2450-low-voltage-contact-closure-interface-1-in-1-out) This one uses both RF and power line signals, and works with Insteon devices (e.g. plug-in relays, etc.) It is more reliable than X10, but costs a little more. Also, the input is designed for 5V, not 12V. This is easy to solve with a voltage divider made up of two resistors, say 1500 ohms from the 12V line to the 5V input, and 1000 ohms from the 5V input to ground. Cheap and cheerful!

Answer (score 0):

There are products to do exactly that, called 'Wireless Light Switches'.

Such a product would have 2 components.

- Transmitter - A wall-mount rocker switch, without wires or batteries.
- Receiver - A switching unit with 'Line', 'Neutral' and 'Output' terminals.

The indoor range would easily cover a standard dwelling unit.

An on-line search for 'wireless light switch' would be fruitful.