# wireless relay product that can be triggered by continuous voltage

Tags: relay, wireless

Does anyone know of a way to wirelessly triggered (by continuous voltage) a relay? Obviously that is how a wired relay works, I just want to add a load to a spot that has 12v already wired but i don't want to have to run a trigger wire to that spot.

Ideally I would like to simply connect a premade transmitter to a existing switch. For my current application I have a light on one side of my boat, I want to make another light on the other side go on as well but without running a cable to it. I just want to put a relay inline and leave its switch on such that the switch on the other side light controls both lights.

I have found almost what i want in the form a of a relay and a small key fob remote, but that is not what i need. Alternatively I might be better asking how to make a transmitter for the above product that is triggered by applying a constant voltage??? The above light project is my current application, but if I could make/buy something it could be applied all over my boat and be really useful in avoiding the pain and destruction involved in running wires on my boat.

Comment: Shopping is off-topic. [Exact Duplicates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517770/wireless-relay-triggered-by-continuous-voltage) are also against the rules.

Comment: Sorry, just looking for a solution.  I was told: "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one."  So that is what I did....

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `triggered by continuous voltage` ... `triggered` means that a reaction will occur as a result of some action .... that is usually a transition between states of some physical parameter ... there is no event in continuous voltage that could be used as a trigger

Comment: Perhaps it is too simplistic a question, and I -- a layman--  do not have the correct terminology.  As you know with a common relay when you give it voltage (for this example 12v) it makes a magnetic field that draws 2 contacts together and in turn completes a circuit.  If I connected what I would refer to as the "trigger" wire (as apposed to the ground or the load wires) to a switch (12v) such that when the switch was "on" it was lighting up a light bulb as well as giving 12v to the relay i could use a switch that is already in existence to do 2 things.

Comment: THat is what I want to do, but with out a "trigger" wire.  I envision  a transmitter thingy, that when it has 12v applied to it, it  yells across the room "turn on now" to a relay, and the relay does that.  then when 12v is removed it yells back "off now dude" and the relay goes off.  i'm sure one could program a arduino to do that, but i was hoping there was a more simplistic approach.

Comment: Go with the Arduino, or a simpler MCU.  Buying things is off topic, building them not.  And there are libraries for dealing with those kinds of radio relays.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find a remote-control relay with serparate on and off buttons a relay circuit can be built to pulse the on and off buttons as power comes and goes in the monitored circuit,.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkRXq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
use 5V relays for the on off relays and a 12V relay for RLY1  this will ensure that the circuit will respond to slowly rising or slowly falling inputs.